# SQL query for 2 different conditions and columns from same table

Tags: sql, join

I have a 'transaction' table as below:

| id | user_id | amount | transaction_mode | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 55 | Joined the Contest | 2023-10-07 |
| 2 | 1 | 25 | For Winning the Contest | 2023-10-07 |
| 3 | 2 | 33 | Joined the Contest | 2023-10-12 |
| 4 | 2 | 10 | For Winning the Contest | 2023-10-12 |
| 5 | 2 | 58 | Joined the Contest | 2023-10-26 |
| 6 | 2 | 22 | Joined the Contest | 2023-10-26 |
| 7 | 1 | 40 | For Winning the Contest | 2023-10-26 |
| 8 | 1 | 10 | For Winning the Contest | 2023-10-26 |

So 'Joined the Contest' mode in the table is that the customer has paid the entry free for playing the contest. After the contest is completed, only few are the winners which is the mode as 'For Winning the Contest'. So I am trying to calculate the amount for joined the contest daily and amount of winning the contest daily for the dates.

So the query for Joining the contest is:

```
  SELECT SUM(amount) AS entry_amount, created_date AS date
    FROM transaction
   WHERE transaction_mode = 'Joined the Contest' 
GROUP BY CAST(created_date AS date);
```

The query for winning the contest is:

```
  SELECT SUM(amount) AS credited_amount, created_date AS date 
    FROM transaction
   WHERE transaction_mode = 'For Winning the Contest' 
GROUP BY CAST(created_date AS date);
```

But I want to get this output all in one like this:

| entry_amount | credited_amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 25 | 2023-10-07 |
| 33 | 10 | 2023-10-12 |
| 80 | 50 | 2023-10-26 |

But I want to get this output through a single SQL query, where I tried this first:

```
   SELECT SUM(amount) AS entry_amount, created_date AS date 
     FROM transaction
    WHERE transaction_mode = 'Joined the Contest' 
UNION ALL
   SELECT SUM(amount) AS credited_amount, created_date AS date 
     FROM transaction
    WHERE transaction_mode = 'For Winning the Contest' 
 GROUP BY CAST(created_date AS date);
```

But this SQL query returns only the entry amount and not the credited_amount.

Comment: use conditional aggregate. `...sum(case when transaction_mode = 'Joined' then amount END), sum(case when transaction_mode = 'Won' then amount END)...`

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; please do not tag conflicting products. [Edit] your question to (re)tag the product you are *really* using and *only* that product.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_mode = 'Joined the Contest' THEN amount END) as entry_amount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_mode = 'For Winning the Contest' THEN amount END) as credited_amount,
       created_date as [date]
FROM transactions
GROUP BY created_date
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MYtZodTv)